# best fitting curve from plot in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have a probability density function in a plot called ph that i derived from two samples of data, by the help of a user of stackoverflow, in this way

```
 few <-read.table('outcome.dat',head=TRUE)
 many<-read.table('alldata.dat',head=TRUE)
 mh <- hist(many$G,breaks=seq(0,1.,by=0.03), plot=FALSE)
 fh <- hist(few$G, breaks=mh$breaks, plot=FALSE)
 ph <- fh
 ph$density <- fh$counts/(mh$counts+0.001)
 plot(ph,freq=FALSE,col="blue")
```

I would like to fit the best curve of the plot of ph, but i can't find a working method. 
how can i do this? I have to extract the vaule from ph and then works on they? or there is same function that works on

```
 plot(ph,freq=FALSE,col="blue")
```

directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you want to perform a curve fit to the data in ph, then something along the lines of
`nls(FUN, cbind(ph$counts, ph$mids),...)`   may work.  You need to know what sort of function 'FUN' you think the histogram data should fit, e.g.  normal distribution.   Read the help  file on `nls()` to learn how to set up starting "guess" values for the coefficients in FUN.

If you simply want to overlay a curve onto the histogram, then `smoo<-spline(ph$mids,ph$counts);
lines(smoo$x,smoo$y)`

will come close to doing that.  You may have to adjust the x and/or y scaling.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a density function?

```
x = rnorm(1000)
hist(x, breaks = 30, freq = FALSE)
lines(density(x), col = "red")
```

Comment: I actually think this is a better way to draw a line than my spline solution.