# How to fit a gaussian to a histogram in R?

Tags: r, curve-fitting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fitting a density curve to a histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497539/fitting-a-density-curve-to-a-histogram-in-r)
>   [best fitting curve from plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502027/best-fitting-curve-from-plot-in-r)

I have a set of data that when plotted in a histogram is a Gaussian distribution. I have read the data in from a .csv file that looks like this:

```
"values"
1.29989
1.15652
1.27818
1.19699
1.28243
1.19433
1.10991
...
```

using `data<-read.csv("~/peak.csv")` ... so I create a histogram using `hist(data$values)`.
I want to be able to fit a Gaussian to this histogram and compare the fitted function's sigma and mean to the sigma and mean calculated from the data.

Everywhere that I have looked mentions `nls` and `glm` but I cannot figure out how to use these functions to fit a Gaussian to a histogram, even after doing `?nls` and `?glm`. Please help?

Comment: Surely a duplicate: Search strategy that seems obvious: `[r] fit distribution histogram`

Comment: Try `?lm` and `lm(values ~ 1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the built in functions you can do it like this:

```
library("MASS")
data<-read.csv("~/peak.csv")
fitdistr(data, "normal")
```

Just keep in mind that for a gaussian this is just calculating the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: how to handle the data, if you have number of `0s`?